# Is there a way to get an event from windows on every new process that is started?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, native

I want to get a notification each time a new process is started by the operating system.
Note that I need to that in native code (I know it can be done in managed code using System.Management members).
Extra points if there is a way to get it before the process starts running :) (i.e in during its initialization)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using a driver is that you will require permission to install it, but otherwise I think is the safest method.

In user space you can try to create a window hook which will work if such application uses a windows, but is otherwise quite obnoxious.

On the other hand you can try to use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx), which is the underlying technology used in C#. You can look for pointers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start) anwers and this [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, the link to WMI is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A real-time ETW trace will give you this information with low system overhead. Note that this will not let you *hook* process creation (i.e. it will only be a notification, you cannot control whether or not the process actually gets started)