# How to detect when a running process starts another

Tags: c#

Is there a way to know when a process (an executable) starts another process (another executable?) And what that new process is?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to do this programmatically it is a tricky task but still doable, you would need to get every process that is running and find it's parent process ID. Then compare to the previous check if it is new.

If you simply want to find out about a specific program try this application by Microsoft:
[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)