# preventing a program from starting when another prog is running (Windows)

Tags: c#

I have 2 programs. I want to build an external tool, which prevents one of the programs from starting, when the other program is already running, and vice versa.
I can't touch the code of either of the two programs.

I want to do it preferably with C#, but a scripting language will also be ok.

Can anyone help me with the concept how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Write your tool as a windows service that keeps running in background and kills the second program if it starts. It can find out when a new process starts by listening to WMI events see [.NET Events for Process executable start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start)

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do that. If you are using C# you should be getting the process name using the GetProcessesByName(). It would look something like this 
     Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
If you know the process name you can just kill the process 
Or else use the [Semaphore Class] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).