# Is there a way to recieve a event about a process starting in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

TL;DR

I have written a program in C++ to close all "new" programs that start that were not running when my program started. Currently I do this by capturing all PIDs and then constantly checking all registered applications against this list. Those who are not on my list I attempt to close/kill. This is very CPU intensive for such a simple task. Is there a way to receive some sort of windows event so I don't need to have a very active thread?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx) hook which might do what I need it to do, but it kind of seems geared towards other purposes, not quite what I need.

In a nutshell:

Is there a event I can receive from windows right after/before a process launches?

Comment: Check out kiosk mode. If it has not been discontinued. Old functionality.

Comment: you need register own callback with `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine[Ex]`

Comment: Huh, that might be what I need. The description is kind of confusing if it will work exactly like I want it too, but I am going to give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would do this in user-mode and without polling and the only thing I can think of that comes close is [WMI events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392396(v=vs.85).aspx).

A C++ example can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425(v=vs.85).aspx). You might also want to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144137/3501) about the differences between __InstanceCreationEvent and Win32_ProcessStartTrace.

Comment: *without polling* - but how this WMI events internally implemented ?  i mean how wmi itself got notification about process start/stop ? if exist some user mode api for this(without polling) we can direct call it yourself, without wmi and rpc. if wmi do polling yourself - this nonsense use - can and poll direct without wmi

Comment: I would assume WMI does not poll but uses  PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine or ETW. I don't know why there is no simple user-mode API that does the same thing.

Comment: According to https://www.fireeye.com/content/dam/fireeye-www/global/en/current-threats/pdfs/wp-windows-management-instrumentation.pdf WMI extrinsic events like Win32_
ProcessStartTrace do not poll.

Comment: yes, you right. wmi use `krnlprov.dll` here which got events from kernel via ETW on *Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process* (`{22FB2CD6-0E7B-422B-A0C7-2FAD1FD0E716}`) provider