# C# Wait for a Progam/Process to start

Tags: c#, process, startup, wait

How can I make a program that will activate a code when a program/process stated was opened without starting the stated program itself.

Right now I have this code:

```
while (!IsProcessOpen("ThisProcess")) //"IsProcessOpen" just checks whether the program stated is open in the task manager.
{

}
gopatch.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(gopatch_DoWork);
gopatch.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(gopatch_RunWorkerCompleted);
gopatch.RunWorkerAsync();
```

but this way uses way too much cpu. Is there a way to make it use less cpu but get the job done as I wanted it to?

Comment: Use WMI to handle the event asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Thread.Sleep` method in your while loop to prevent excessive CPU consumption. It's not optimal, but it's simple. If you need something better, try using events. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start) describes how to use the `ManagementEventWatcher` to do so.

Comment: I would go with hooks and the above code. Let an event handler fire off when a new process starts, and then check to see if the required program is running at that time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx

Comment: ManagementEventWatcher is the cleanest way to go.