# Closing Application Using C#

Tags: c#

I am Using a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) Form Application and I want to know how can I exit environment if the process `conquer.exe` was closed. I am Using this Code in a Timer but nothing happens if `conquer.exe` was closed.

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process exe in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (exe.ProcessName.StartsWith("conquer"))
    {
        exe.WaitForExit();
        if (exe.HasExited)
        {
            Application.Exit();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the case where no process exists with name equal to conquer?

Comment: Don't use a timer,If the process is running it blocks the MainThread until the Process is closed,If the process exits before the timer ticks then the you cant use your function.Use a Background Thread to check the existence of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
private ManagementEventWatcher WatchForProcessEnd(string processName)
    {
        string queryString =
            "SELECT TargetInstance" +
            "  FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent " +
            "WITHIN  10 " +
            " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
            "   AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + processName + "'";

        // The dot in the scope means use the current machine
        string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

        // Create a watcher and listen for events
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
        watcher.EventArrived += ProcessEnded;
        watcher.Start();
        return watcher;
    }

    private void ProcessEnded(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject) e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;
        string processName = targetInstance.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} process ended", processName));
    }
```

Source : [.NET Events for Process executable start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start)

Answer (score 1):

As @Steven Liekens suggested,We can use the **Process.Exited** event to keep track of the application state.

Create a list to store all the processes with same name.

```
List<Process> selectedProcesses = new List<Process>();
```

Then get all the processes with same name.

```
        // Gets the processes with given name
        // If one or more instances are running
        foreach (Process exe in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (exe.ProcessName.Contains("WINWORD"))
            {
                exe.Exited += exe_Exited;
                selectedProcesses.Add(exe);
            }
        }
```

Then in the **Exited** event check whether the list is empty.

```
    void exe_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If all the procees have been exited
        if (selectedProcesses.Count == 0)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        // Else remove a process from the list
        selectedProcesses.RemoveAt(selectedProcesses.Count - 1) ;
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't account for the case where there is more than 1 WINWORD process. Instead, you might want to (1) make a list of all qualifying processes, (2) remove a process from the list when the `Process.Exited` event is triggered, and (3) exit the application when the list is empty.

Comment: @StevenLiekens That's true.Thanks for pointing it out.I have modified the answer according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process exe = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("conquer"));
if(exe != null)
{
    exe.WaitForExit();
    exe.refresh();
    if(exe.HasExited)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        Enviroment.Exit(0);
    }
}
else
{
    //Conquer process has already exited or was not running.
}
```

I also agree with @Naren this code should be run in a background worker thread. You shouldn't need to run this in a timer, in fact you shouldn't. If you run this is a background worker thread the `exe.WaitForExit();` call will suspend the background thread until the process has exited.

If the application you are running this code in is dependant on the conquer process then if it is not running on startup you could start it yourself and then wait for exit... Again this code should be run in a background thread.

```
Process exe = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("conquer"));
if(exe == null)
{
    exe = new Process();
    exe.StartInfo.FileName = "conquer.exe"
    exe.Start();

    exe.WaitForExit();
    exe.refresh();
    if(exe.HasExited)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        Enviroment.Exit(0);
    }
}
if(exe != null)
{
    exe.WaitForExit();
    exe.refresh();
    if(exe.HasExited)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        Enviroment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely you'll be able to actually catch the process exiting if you are doing this in a timer. If you miss the process being exited, it won't be returned as a result of getting the running processes in your for loop. Because it never find it you will never find any process starting with "conquer".

A safer option is just to check if the process is in the list of running applications and exit if you can't find it.

```
using System.Linq;

if (!System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("conquer.exe", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
  Application.Exit();
}
```

Be careful of using StartsWith since you could mistakenly pick up other processes starting the with name "conquer".