# Do something if certain process is running without timer

Tags: c#, process, timer, performance

I'm using a `System.Timers.Timer` to check if a certain process is running on an interval of 1000ms, and if so, to output it on a string, e.g.:

```
System.Timers.Timer bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeText);
bTimer.Interval = 1000;
bTimer.Enabled = true;

private void ChangeText(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("notepad"))
        {
            lblText.Text = "Notepad is running.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblText.Text = "Notepad is not running.";
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering, is there a more efficient way to do this, without a timer? For example something that monitors running processes without having to read the memory every second?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if (process == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("process is not running");
}
else
{
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("process exited");
        };
}
```