# On the long-running operating system using the Process.GetProcesses() performance problems

Tags: c#, .net

I develop features require regular scans running processes list, restart the process of exiting the exception.

I use `Process.GetProcesses()` to get the list of currently running processes, which on most computers does not have a performance problem.

But when I deployed on a server that is running for a long time (has been running for 147 days, new PID have been million), using the `Process.GetProcesses()` processing time up to 100 milliseconds, and normal `Process.GetProcesses()` processing time is within a few milliseconds. This affects system performance.

```
ProcessesProtectionThread = new Thread(() => {
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                //I use the Stopwatch, and I found that almost always deal with this line
                // of code.
                var currentProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
                var protectedProcesses = currentProcesses.Where(item => protectProcessesNames.Contains(item.ProcessName.ToUpper()));
                var protectedProcessesPaths = protectedProcesses.Select(item => item?.MainModule?.FileName?.ToUpper()).Distinct().ToList();
                var restartProcessesPaths = protectProcessesPaths.Where(item => !protectedProcessesPaths.Contains(item)).ToList();
                RestartProcess(restartProcessesPaths, currentProcesses);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
            catch (Exception ex) { LogHelper.WriteExMessage(ex); }
            finally { Thread.Sleep(ProcessProtectionInterval); }
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
    catch (Exception ex) { LogHelper.WriteExMessage(ex); }
});
ProcessesProtectionThread.IsBackground = true;
ProcessesProtectionThread.Start();
```

Who can tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just how many times per second are you calling `Process.GetProcesses()`?

Comment: @MickyD This is configurable, usually once a second. But I need to run multiple(now 3) threads at the same time, doing different operations.

Comment: Perhaps post some of your code?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @VisualVincent Protecting a process list, if the protected process has exited, then restart the protected process.

Comment: Perhaps utilizing a [**WMI alternative**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/857946/3740093) would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your advice! However, using WMI to read ProcessInformationList is not always able to read ProcessFileName.

Comment: Read the process name yourself via .NET's `Process` class. Just get the ID from WMI and pass it to `Process.GetProcessById()`.

Comment: @VisualVincent I tried it, and I found that using the Process.GetProcessById than the Process.GetProcesses processing time longer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution in the MSDN forum.

> Maybe obtain the Process object, then use WaitForExit. Or set the EnableRaisingEvents to true and handle the Exited event. Then you do not need the periodic loops.