# Is there any way to detect when the Windows Security Dialog is open?

Tags: c#, .net

I have application with C# and want to get notification when the Windows Security Dialog is open in Windows, I handle it by polling and get all windows dialog and check by caption, but it's not proper way and caption could be different (like in diff language).

So is there any way, my app get notified when the dialog is appeared?

[image]

Comment: Possibly not. If it was the UAC 'do you accept' screen, then very very no, but this screen... a soft No. Using some old win32 api calls might let you catch it's process id appearing

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already handle the UAC (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751919/how-to-check-is-uac-is-currently-blacking-out-the-screen) and works fine, but I couldn't find any proper solution for `Windows Security`